# Undo next value in SQL Server sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to undo the next value in a SQL Server sequence?

My sequence is 3 times the wanted value.

Comment: Is there a reason that having a gap in your sequence is a big deal?

Comment: it's is highly unwanted

Comment: Seems like you are probably giving the sequence too much weight. But it is simple to restart them. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Yeah, worrying about whether you have gaps in your sequence should not be a thing.

Comment: What do you use the sequence for? "it is highly unwanted" is just another way of saying "having a gap in the sequence is a big deal", not a reason *why* it is a big deal/highly unwanted

Comment: *Why* is it "highly unwanted"? What business critical process means that having gaps is a problem? If this is so important, what happens when you delete a row in one of the tables that uses the `SEQUENCE`? Do you need to retrospectively change the valies of all the rows that contained values used after that value?

Comment: "it's is highly unwanted" probably means you have a bad database design

Comment: Something selected the next value in the sequence.  That something can throw the value away.  Does it grab the next value too soon?  Or another process can later delete all records that used the sequence value.  If you need to reuse "freed" sequence values, then you likely need a different process to get the next value.  IDENTITY columns and sequence values are designed for speed and concurrency.  A solution filling the gaps will likely block while it grabs the value and marks it as in use.  Depending on the requirements, you might need to sacrifice concurrency and performance to fill gaps.

Comment: You can use the option `RESTART WITH` in `ALTER SEQUENCE`. [alter-sequence-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)